# Как связать добавляемые метки линиями?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

При нажатии кнопки в центре карты появляется метка, нужно, чтобы новые метки были соединены с последней добавленной и при этом их все можно было двигать.(был вопрос похожий, но я запутался, простите)

```
    function init() {
    var opt = {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: [11]
    };
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", opt, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

    var myPolyline = new ymaps.Polyline([
    ]);

    $("#button")
        .on('click', function () {    // Добавить точку
            let nameOfPoint = document.getElementById('point').value;

            var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {}, {
                draggable: true,
                properties: {
                    // Контент метки.
                    hintContent: nameOfPoint
                }
            });

            myMap.geoObjects
                .add(myPlacemark);

            console.log(myPolyline);

            myPolyline.geometry._coordPath._coordinates.push(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());

                        // Добавляем линии на карту.
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolyline);
            myPlacemark.geometry.events.add('change', function (e) {
                let newCoords = e.get('newCoordinates');
                myPolyline.geometry.set(0, newCoords);
            });
        });
}

ymaps.ready(init);    //подключаем карту
```

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался

```
   function init() {
    var opt = {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: [11]
    };
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", opt, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });

    var myPolyline = new ymaps.Polyline([]);
    let pointNum = 0;
    $("#button")
        .on('click', function () {    // Добавить точку
            let nameOfPoint = document.getElementById('point').value;
            let i = pointNum;
            pointNum++;
            let point = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(),{hintContent: nameOfPoint}, {draggable: true });
            point.geometry.events.add('change', function (e) {
                let newCoords = e.get('newCoordinates');
                console.log(pointNum);

                myPolyline.geometry.set(i, newCoords);
            });
            console.log(point);
            myMap.geoObjects
                .add(point);


            myPolyline.geometry._coordPath._coordinates.push(myMap.getCenter());

                        // Добавляем линии на карту.
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolyline);

        });
}

ymaps.ready(init);    //подключаем карту
```